# Cost of ObjectA===ObjectB

Tags: javascript, arrays

How does === operator work for objects in JavaScript? I want to know this because I want to know what is the cost of doing `(ObjectA === ObjectB)`? Since `array.indexOf()` uses === to compare objects and return index does it become a costly operation? (Here array is an array of objects.) I read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) but couldn't understand much.

Comment: Objects in Javascript are compared by reference, not by value, so it's not expensive in terms of lookup. The `===` operator improves on the `==` operator in only one regard, namely it prevents type conversion before checking for equality. Not sure what else you want to know, exactly.

Comment: and two different object can't be equal `{} === {} // false`.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript

Comment: The cost of array.indexOf is not in the comparison, but in the scan/search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### From MDN

> Strict equal (===) Returns true if the operands are equal and of the same type. See also Object.is and sameness in JS.

### From Tests

There is no way to say exactly what the complexity of the operation itself is without looking at the implementation, but as a general norm its taken as O(1) (until someone proves otherwise).

If you are looking to see if two objects are equal, i.e. are both reference to the same object `===` is the fastest when objects are same. I have the tests done [here](https://jsperf.com/js-efficiency-comparison) and [here](https://jsperf.com/javascript-strict-equality-efficiency-in-cases).
[image]

So `ObjectA === ObjectB` takes as much time as `d = 1 + 1`. So I think its safe to say that its a O(1) complexity operation and happens by the comparison of the respective objectIDs of the objects in question.[image]

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know what is the cost of doing `(ObjectA === ObjectB)`

It's approximately the same as the cost of doing `1 === 1`.

Even if this were an expensive operation, which it's not (at all), what else would you do? If you want to compare, you have to compare.

Answer (score 1):

The cost in terms of complexity is certainly `O(1)`, as it might be critical at some point. `Array.indexOf` is `O(n)`, but don't worry, you won't get a quadratic complexity for comparing `n` times some objects.

On the other hand, you have to keep in mind that using `n` times `Array.indexOf` is actually quadratic.

As a guideline, I generally forbid myself using `Array.indexOf` in a loop, and find a way to use a hash instead.